# Spring boot with micrometer Elasticsearch registry indexes only empty documents

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a simple spring boot **2.1.7.RELEASE** project using micrometer Elasticsearch registry (using Elasticsearch 7.2.0). The project is available [here](https://github.com/dome313/micrometer-elastic/tree/elastic-no-source) on github. It has only two classes and looks like this

**pom.xml** has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-elastic</artifactId>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and two classes:
**MicrometerElasticApplication**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicrometerElasticApplication {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MicrometerElasticApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

and **TestController**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public void sendMessage() {
    System.out.println("Received a test message");
  }
}
```

Once I start the app, I can see in the logs

```
i.m.elastic.ElasticMeterRegistry         : publishing metrics to elastic every 1m
```

which means metrics are sent, but then when I check what is indexed in the Elasticsearch, I can only see documents like this one

```
{
    "_index": "metrics-2019-08",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "nWuMdWwBxBoi4XILEHVK",
    "_score": 1.0
}
```

so no fields, just document metadata. Even after hitting the `/test` endpoint server times, nothing changes in the `metrics` index.

My understanding from reading the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-meter) and checking the common properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) is that Spring by default is going to add metrics for JVM, CPU... and even measure timings for all MVC requests. Right now, I'm not getting anything of those, just empty documents. Setting the property `management.metrics.web.server.auto-time-requests` to **true** does not change anything.

Anyone see what I'm missing here?

**UPDATE**

I put a break point to `ElasticMeterRegistry.publish` method and the request sent to Elaticsearch `/_bulk` API looks good to me

```
POST http://localhost:9200/metrics-2019-08/_bulk

{ "index" : {} }
{"@timestamp":"2019-08-09T10:49:18.826Z","name":"jvm_memory_max","type":"gauge","area":"heap","id":"PS Survivor Space","value":1.5204352E7}
{ "index" : {} }
{"@timestamp":"2019-08-09T10:49:18.826Z","name":"jvm_threads_states","type":"gauge","state":"terminated","value":0.0}
...
```

When I send this request using Postman, all documents are saved as empty docs, although 
Elasticsearch does not report any errors, `"errors": false` in the response

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "errors": false,
    "items": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The index `metrics-2019-08` create by the `ElasticMeterRegistry` has in its mapping set `_source` to false

```
GET http://localhost:9200/metrics-2019-08/_mapping
```

Response is

```
"metrics-2019-08": {
    "mappings": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": false
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

From the Elasticserch documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/mapping-source-field.html)

> _source field itself is not indexed (and thus is not searchable), but it is stored so that it can be returned when executing fetch requests,
>   like get or search.

So if `_source` is false, then every request to get documents returns empty source. The rational behind disabling this is documents are only going to be used for aggregations (avg, min, max, sum...), `_source` is not needed for those, so to save disc space `_source` is not stored.

To disable this behavior set `management.metrics.export.elastic.auto-create-index` to **false**. If you already run it with **true**, you need to delete the existing template with

```
DELETE http://localhost:9200/_template/metrics_template
```

After that, create the template for metrics indices like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_template/metrics_template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "metrics*"
  ],
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "count": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "sum": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "mean": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "duration": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "max": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "total": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "unknown": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "active": {
        "type": "double"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This template is the same as one used by micrometer, apart from `_source` which is set to **true**. After this, the documents will appear in fetch requests, like get or search.

Comment: I did that and it worked, but then my other application (which also uses Spring/Micrometer, worked and for which I didn't disable auto-create-inde) started to throw: `i.m.e.ElasticMeterRegistry : failed to send metrics to elastic: {"took":581,"errors":true,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"metrics-dispatcher-2020-06","_type":"doc","_id":"o5CmnXIB-_AiyWgfG-T4","status":400,"error":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update enabled setting for [_source]]"}}}`. Only after I deleted the template, both applications work. Any idea why?

Comment: in your case, there are two apps with different values for _source, one with false and the other one with true. In Elasticsearch you cannot update the mapping value of _source field. That's why the second service it's failing on startup, it's updating the mapping with _source set to false.

Comment: It is not necessary to include the source for the metrics to be indexed properly.  They may not show up when accessing an index, but they are there in Elasticsearch.  You will need to use something like Kibana to visualize the data.  This Github issue explains it: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1629

Comment: It worked for me without creating the template myself
Just disable auto-create-index and delete previously indices, and let micrometer recreate the index fixed it!